# Updating a tableadapter with duplicated keys

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable, sql-update, tableadapter

I'm new in updating databases and apparently I'm not good in it.

Details :

- I use tableadapter (I don't know if this is the best way) to refer to my database in a .mdf file
- My table has two columns and the first one is the `Primary Key`
- The table has already some rows
- I fill my tableadapter with : `Me.CCListTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HQSdbDataSet.CCList)`

What I'm trying to do :

1. I create a new datatable based on my CCListTable : `Dim ccDataTable As CCListDataTable = New CCListDataTable`
2. I import a .csv file with new rows (> 3000 lines) using CsvReader into this new datatable. There are rows who already exists into my database
3. I try then to add these new rows into the tableadapter with :

   `Me.CCListBindingSource.EndEdit()
   Me.CCListTableAdapter.Update(ccDataTable)`

But it doesn't work and I get an `SqlException` with `Violation of PRIMARY KEY [...] Cannot insert duplicate key`. Ok like I said I know there are duplicate keys but I don't want to insert these but only update the tableadapter with the new rows.

Here the sub that I have created to import my CSV (if it can help) :

```
Public Sub ImportCSV2Data(ByVal filename As String, ByRef datatable As DataTable, ByVal column2Import() As Integer,
                          ByVal tableAlreadyExist As Boolean)

    Dim csvCopy As CachedCsvReader = New CachedCsvReader(New StreamReader(filename), True, ";"c)
    csvCopy.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByEmpty

    Dim headers() As String = csvCopy.GetFieldHeaders
    If column2Import.Length > 0 AndAlso column2Import(0) > -1 Then
        If tableAlreadyExist Then
            While csvCopy.ReadNextRecord()
                Dim csvRow As DataRow = datatable.NewRow
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                For Each column As Integer In column2Import
                    Select Case datatable.Columns(i).DataType.Name
                        Case "String"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvCopy(column)) Then
                                csvRow(i) = ""
                            Else
                                csvRow(i) = Convert.ToString(csvCopy(column))
                            End If
                        Case "Int32"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvCopy(column)) Then
                                csvRow(i) = DBNull.Value
                            Else
                                csvRow(i) = Convert.ToInt32(csvCopy(column))
                            End If
                        Case "Double"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvCopy(column)) Then
                                csvRow(i) = DBNull.Value
                            Else
                                csvRow(i) = Convert.ToDouble(csvCopy(column))
                            End If
                        Case "DateTime"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvCopy(column)) Then
                                csvRow(i) = Nothing
                            Else
                                csvRow(i) = Convert.ToDateTime(csvCopy(column))
                            End If
                        Case "Boolean"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvCopy(column)) Then
                                csvRow(i) = DBNull.Value
                            Else
                                csvRow(i) = Convert.ToBoolean(csvCopy(column))
                            End If
                    End Select
                    i += 1
                Next
                datatable.Rows.Add(csvRow)
            End While
        Else
            For Each column As Integer In column2Import
                datatable.Columns.Add(headers(column))
            Next
            While csvCopy.ReadNextRecord()
                Dim csvRow As DataRow = datatable.NewRow
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                For Each column As Integer In column2Import
                    csvRow(i) = csvCopy(column)
                    i += 1
                Next
                datatable.Rows.Add(csvRow)
            End While
        End If
    Else
        If tableAlreadyExist Then
            While csvCopy.ReadNextRecord()
                Dim csvRow As DataRow = datatable.NewRow
                For i = 0 To csvCopy.FieldCount - 1
                    Select Case datatable.Columns(i).DataType.Name
                        Case "String"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvCopy(i)) Then
                                csvRow(i) = ""
                            Else
                                csvRow(i) = Convert.ToString(csvCopy(i))
                            End If
                        Case "Int32"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvCopy(i)) Then
                                csvRow(i) = DBNull.Value
                            Else
                                csvRow(i) = Convert.ToInt32(csvCopy(i))
                            End If
                        Case "Double"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvCopy(i)) Then
                                csvRow(i) = DBNull.Value
                            Else
                                csvRow(i) = Convert.ToDouble(csvCopy(i))
                            End If
                        Case "DateTime"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvCopy(i)) Then
                                csvRow(i) = Nothing
                            Else
                                csvRow(i) = Convert.ToDateTime(csvCopy(i))
                            End If
                        Case "Boolean"
                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(csvCopy(i)) Then
                                csvRow(i) = DBNull.Value
                            Else
                                csvRow(i) = Convert.ToBoolean(csvCopy(i))
                            End If
                    End Select
                Next
                datatable.Rows.Add(csvRow)
            End While
        Else
            For Each header As String In headers
                datatable.Columns.Add(header)
            Next
            While csvCopy.ReadNextRecord()
                Dim csvRow As DataRow = datatable.NewRow
                For i = 0 To csvCopy.FieldCount - 1
                    csvRow(i) = csvCopy(i)
                Next
                datatable.Rows.Add(csvRow)
            End While
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

What am I missing?

Comment: My Primary Key is an `Int` and what do you mean by "need to know how I set the value of my key when I import my rows"?

Comment: We need to know if the column has an autoincrement property. You have primary key violation, so we need to see the part code of code which import the rows from csv. The problem seems evident but it's impossible to solve it with such information.

Comment: No the Column has not an autoincrement property. I'm going to edit my question to post my code that import the CSV. But I don't think that the issue is coming from the import because through `Console.Writeline` I can see that it import everything quite well. I think that the issue is coming from a duplicate key : one existing into my datatable with my imported rows and the sameone existing into my old database.

Comment: I will try to help but I would like to know before, does the code to import CSV works? You get an exception when you try to update the table, but is the correct at this time? Did you try for example to display the data somewhere before the update code. - The code for the import from csv seems to be generic (not specific to your DataTable). The data in the CSV file must have same schema (ie same **Number** of columns and in the same **Order**, same **DataType**).

Comment: First of all thanks for trying to help me... To answer your question : Yes It works quite well... Same number of columns and same order and same datatype... Because I created my datatable this way : `Dim ccDataTable As CCListDataTable = New CCListDataTable`. The CCListDataTable is coming from my dataset. But before posting my question here I wasn't sure and verified with `console.writeline()` and it shows all my csv rows... And I imported it also into a datagridview where I could see my two columns in the same order with all my csv rows...

Comment: OK, So the principle of a *primary key* is that it **must be unique**. Since you have already data in your table, you need to be sure that data in the CSV file do not contain duplicates. **Otherwise, you need to write your own logic to replace duplicate keys with others** (you mentioned the key has no increment property). Make sense?

Comment: Ok on the fact that a `Primary Key`has to be unique and in my case it is... My csv file contains the old lines and new ones thats why there are duplicate keys. I just want my .Net application to update my datatable with the new ones and maybe verify the old ones with these in my csv file to see if it is completly the same or if they should be updated. The key has no increment property because it is a unique reference code.

Comment: Ok finally I merged my new datatable with the old one and had what I wanted but why when I close my application it doesn't save into the database?

Comment: could you post the code that updates the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code who resolves my issue :

```
    'Create a DataTable with the same schema of your DataBase
    Dim ccDataTable As CCListDataTable = New CCListDataTable

    'Import here your csvFile into your new DataTable
    Call ImportCSV2Data(dialog2openFile.FileName, ccDataTable, {0, 2}, True)

    'Merge it with the correct DataTable from your Database (False to recognize the changes)
    Me.HQSdbDataSet.CCList.Merge(ccDataTable, False)

    'Then update your DataBase
    Me.CCListBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.CCListTableAdapter.Update(Me.HQSdbDataSet.CCList)
```

If you loose the changes when you close your application in debug mode it is normal because you have two databases one ine your application and the other in the debug folder and the one erase the other when you enter the debug mode but when you launch your application whitout debug mode it is ok.
**Other solution :** In the propriety of you database select 'NEVER COPY'